# How can i use Profilebase class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2010

i try to use asp.net profile, i try to give inheritance with ProfileBase

```
public class dort_islem : ProfileBase
{
    public int ilk_sayi { get; set; }
    public int ikinci_sayi { get; set; }
}
```

```
  <anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
  <profile enabled="true" inherits="dort_islem">
   <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="profiller"/>
   </providers>
   <properties>
    <add name="ad" allowAnonymous="true" defaultValue="yusuf"/>
    <add name="soy_ad" allowAnonymous="true"/>
    <add name="sevdigi_renk" allowAnonymous="true" type="System.Drawing.Color" serializeAs="Binary" />
        <group name="detaylar">
          <add name="numara" type="Integer" allowAnonymous="true"/>
          <add name="giris_tarihi" type="Date" allowAnonymous="true"/>
          <add name="cinsiyet" allowAnonymous="true"/>
          <add name="adres" allowAnonymous="true"/>
        </group>
   </properties>
  </profile>
```

but if i try to use these codes Default.aspx:
[image]

How can i see ilk_sayi from dort_islem class? Regards....

Answer (score 10):

You are missing a *few* implementation details.

```
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace VideoShow
{
    public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
    {
        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
        {
            return Create(username) as UserProfile;
        }
        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
        {
            return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return base["Description"] as string; }
            set { base["Description"] = value; }
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
        public string Location
        {
            get { return base["Location"] as string; }
            set { base["Location"] = value; }
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
        public string FavoriteMovie
        {
            get { return base["FavoriteMovie"] as string; }
            set { base["FavoriteMovie"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to  hook that up in the profile section of web.config - notice that I've included inherits="VideoShow.UserProfile" in the profile declaration:

```
<profile inherits="VideoShow.UserProfile">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="VideoShowConnectionString"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
```

With that done, I can grab an instance of the custom profile class and set a property:

```
//Write to a user profile from a textbox value
UserProfile profile = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(currentUser.UserName);
profile.FavoriteMovie = FavoriteMovie.Text;
profile.Save();
```

from http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx

Comment: @Phsika - I suggest that you download a working example and examine it.