# What's the best way to give myself easy access to the UserProfile object in a controller in MVC4?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

### Considerations

I created a new MVC4 internet application. Out of the box, it comes with this class in the account models:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

It looks like a good place to add all my other user information and to link my tables to. The fact that it's called a "Profile" seems a bit odd to me, as this appears to be the "base" user class.

I see a table in the database called `webpages_Membership`, but I don't know where the model for that is. When using OpenID to create an account, it doesn't look like a record even gets inserted in there. I believe that's just for local accounts, thus "UserProfile" seems to be the only thing a user is guaranteed to have.

Anyway, the base `Controller` class appears to have a `Profile` property defined as a `ProfileBase` but when I inspect using the debugger, it's a `System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile`, and it doesn't seem to be "filled in". i.e., `IsAnonymous` is true, and `UserName` is `null`, even when I'm logged in.

I'm guessing this is intentional? Am I expected to override that by defining my own base controller?

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889309/65387) and [this article](http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.ca/2012/05/implementing-custom-profile-in-aspnet.html) which talk about extending `ProfileBase`, but that approach seems a bit messy to me.

### Question

With all the aforementioned considerations, it seems best to me to just add all my extra properties to the `UserProfile` class that's already been created for me, then add a new `BaseController` class that extends `Controller`, and override/new the `Profile` property to return a `UserProfile` instead. **(1) Is this a good approach?**

It took me awhile, but I eventually figured out how to get the `UserProfile` object for the currently logged in user:

```
udb.UserProfiles.Single(p => p.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

**(2) Is that the best way to get it?** The `UserProfile` has a `UserId` property, but I can't figure out how to retrieve it. **(3) How can I get the UserId for the currently logged in user?**

I was thinking I could have the property lazy-load the profile so it only hits the database the first time you access that property. I read some other articles that talk about json-serializing the entire user class so it doesn't have to hit the DB every page load, but that sounds even messier, and you risk the data getting out of sync.

### Implementation

Just tried this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private UsersContext _udb = new UsersContext();
    private UserProfile _profile = null;

    public new UserProfile Profile
    {
        get
        {
            if(_profile == null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                _profile = _udb.UserProfiles.Single(p => p.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            }
            return _profile;
        }
    }
}
```

Seems to work flawlessly.

Comment: I really wish someone would answer this. It seems like a good way to do things, but I wonder if it could cause any problems down the line.