# How to get country of a user from active directory form Membership.GetUser(uname)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I am authenticated using active directory . I am successfully authenticate using

```
Membership.ValidateUser(login.UserName, login.Password)
```

method and getting user details from active directory using
`Membership.GetUser(login.UserName)` but I cant get the `country` name how can i get the country name or code from AD anyone please help

Comment: I got the answer by checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674203/ldap-retrieve-a-list-of-all-attributes-values that helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [LDAP - Retrieve a list of all attributes/values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674203/ldap-retrieve-a-list-of-all-attributes-values),

```
  PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(
                                        ContextType.Domain,
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDomainName"],
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADContainer"],
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADUserName"],
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPassword"]);
                UserPrincipal users = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user.UserName);
                DirectoryEntry entry = users.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                PropertyCollection props = entry.Properties;

                if (entry.Properties["countryCode"].Value != null)
                {
                    user.CountryCode = entry.Properties["countryCode"].Value.ToString();
                }
```

It may helps anyone..

Answer (score 1):

The `country` is not a Property by default in `MembershipUser` , unless you manually specified them in your **profile provider**.

U have got to use the [System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.profile.profilebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class .
Here a greate class from @Sky Sanders which also uses the Membership class

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
    {
        return Create(username) as UserProfile;
    }
    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
    {
        return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
    }


    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string CountryCode
    {
        get { return base["countryCode"] as string; }
        set { base["countryCode"] = value; }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return base["Description"] as string; }
        set { base["Description"] = value; }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string Location
    {
        get { return base["Location"] as string; }
        set { base["Location"] = value; }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string FavoriteMovie
    {
        get { return base["FavoriteMovie"] as string; }
        set { base["FavoriteMovie"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Here are some helpful links
[How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)
[How can i use Profilebase class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889158/how-can-i-use-profilebase-class)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried using this but `UserProfile GetUserProfile()` returns null alwys

Comment: I got the answer by checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674203/ldap-retrieve-a-list-of-all-attributes-values that helps me thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Although it is very late, but the tutorial at following link can really help

[How to get User Data from the Active Directory](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6778/How-to-get-User-Data-from-the-Active-Directory)